# How to group XML nodes and their child nodes adding to both a new parent using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, rename

My sample XML looks as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Institutions>
    <Schools>
        <Name>Fictive High School 1</Name>
        <Teachers>
            <FirstName>John</FirstName>
            <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        </Teachers>
    </Schools>
    <Schools>
        <Name>Fictive High School 2</Name>
        <Teachers>
            <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
            <LastName>Brown</LastName>
        </Teachers>
        <Teachers>
            <FirstName>Peter</FirstName>
            <LastName>Griffin</LastName>
        </Teachers>
    </Schools>
</Institutions>
```

The aim is to rename "Teachers" in "Teacher" and to add the renamed nodes to a new parent node "Teachers". The same shall be done with the "Schools" node. So this is what the result XML should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Institutions>
    <Schools>
        <School>
            <Name>Fictive High School 1</Name>
            <Teachers>
                <Teacher>
                    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
                </Teacher>
            </Teachers>
        </School>
        <School>
            <Name>Fictive High School 2</Name>
            <Teachers>
                <Teacher>
                    <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Brown</LastName>
                </Teacher>
                <Teacher>
                    <FirstName>Peter</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Griffin</LastName>
                </Teacher>
            </Teachers>
        </School>
    </Schools>
</Institutions>
```

Now I coded the following XSLT in order to perform the transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- copy everything -->
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- rename Schools to School -->
    <xsl:template match="Schools">
        <School>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </School>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- rename Teachers to Teacher -->
    <xsl:template match="Teachers">
        <Teacher>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </Teacher>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Add each School node to new node Schools -->
        <xsl:template match="/Institutions">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(name() = 'Schools')]"/>
            <Schools>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Schools"/>
            </Schools>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Add each Teacher node to new node Teachers -->
        <xsl:template match="/Institutions/School">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(name() = 'Teachers')]"/>
            <Teachers>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Teachers"/>
            </Teachers>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately the last block does not work, I have tried out different approaches. Do I have to use School instead of Schools? How does the XSLT processor work?

Answer (score 0):

You should only have to override `Institutions` (to create the new `Schools` structure), `Schools` (to create the new `Teachers` structure and rename `Schools` to `School`), and `Teachers` (to rename to `Teacher`)...

**XML Input**

```
<Institutions>
    <Schools>
        <Name>Fictive High School 1</Name>
        <Teachers>
            <FirstName>John</FirstName>
            <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        </Teachers>
    </Schools>
    <Schools>
        <Name>Fictive High School 2</Name>
        <Teachers>
            <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
            <LastName>Brown</LastName>
        </Teachers>
        <Teachers>
            <FirstName>Peter</FirstName>
            <LastName>Griffin</LastName>
        </Teachers>
    </Schools>
</Institutions>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Institutions">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() except Schools"/>
      <Schools>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Schools"/>
      </Schools>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Schools">
      <School>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() except Teachers"/>
        <Teachers>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Teachers"/>
        </Teachers>
      </School>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Teachers">
    <Teacher>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Teacher>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Institutions>
   <Schools>
      <School>
         <Name>Fictive High School 1</Name>
         <Teachers>
            <Teacher>
               <FirstName>John</FirstName>
               <LastName>Doe</LastName>
            </Teacher>
         </Teachers>
      </School>
      <School>
         <Name>Fictive High School 2</Name>
         <Teachers>
            <Teacher>
               <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
               <LastName>Brown</LastName>
            </Teacher>
            <Teacher>
               <FirstName>Peter</FirstName>
               <LastName>Griffin</LastName>
            </Teacher>
         </Teachers>
      </School>
   </Schools>
</Institutions>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel. That worked for me. I was not aware of the approach using the except statement.

Comment: @Dolf - You're very welcome. Please consider accepting this answer by clicking the check mark next to it. Thanks!